# Active Record: get all dates in multiple ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

In my rails(with postgresql) project I have Event model with `start_date` and `end_date` fields. Event date ranges can't overlaps. I want to get all dates with event.

For example:

```
| event id | start_date | end_date   |
| :------: | :--------: | :--------: |
| 51       | 2011-09-27 | 2011-09-29 |
| 70       | 2014-07-23 | 2014-07-26 |
| 71       | 2014-06-30 | 2014-07-01 |
| 77       | 2016-03-10 | 2016-03-11 |
```

Output:

```
[
  2011-09-27,
  2011-09-28,
  2011-09-29,
  2014-07-23,
  2014-07-24,
  2014-07-25,
  2015-08-26,
  2014-06-30,
  2014-06-31,
  2014-07-01,
  2016-03-10,
  2013-03-11
]
```

I try to do a lot and get the result with this code:

```ruby
Event
  .pluck(:start_date, :end_date)
  .map(&:compact).reject(&:empty?) # I have events with null start_date and end_date 
  .map{ |start_date, end_date|
    (start_date.to_date..end_date.to_date).map(&:to_s)
  }
  .flatten
```

But I think it is ugly, is there an elegant way to solve my problem? Maybe with postgresql but I am new in postgresql.

Comment: Your code would look better if you just reorganised it around a scope and instance method so you can: Event.has_start_and_end.dates_in_range.flatten

Answer (score 0):

On model `event.rb`

```
def get_dates
  [created_at, updated_at]
end
```

And get all dates by:

```
Event.all.map(&:get_dates).flatten
```

**Update**

Change the function get_dates.

```
def get_dates
  (Date.parse(start_date.to_s)..Date.parse(end_date.to_s)).to_a
end
```

Comment: Thank for answer, but this is not what I want to get. In this case I only get start and end dates **but not dates between `start_date` and `end_date`**.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. just change the function get_dates, look on my update

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to solve my problem with SQL query

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1bb8b/1)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    start_date date,
    end_date date
)/

INSERT INTO events (id, start_date, end_date) VALUES (51, '2011-09-27', '2011-09-29')/
INSERT INTO events (id, start_date, end_date) VALUES (70, '2014-07-23', '2014-07-26')/
INSERT INTO events (id, start_date, end_date) VALUES (71, '2014-06-30', '2014-07-01')/
INSERT INTO events (id, start_date, end_date) VALUES (77, '2016-03-10', '2016-03-11')/
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH duration AS (
    SELECT start_date as begins
    , end_date as ends
    FROM events
    )
SELECT generate_series( duration.begins, duration.ends, '1 day':: interval):: date
FROM duration;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1bb8b/1/0)**:

```
|             generate_series |
|-----------------------------|
| September, 27 2011 00:00:00 |
| September, 28 2011 00:00:00 |
| September, 29 2011 00:00:00 |
|      July, 23 2014 00:00:00 |
|      July, 24 2014 00:00:00 |
|      July, 25 2014 00:00:00 |
|      July, 26 2014 00:00:00 |
|      June, 30 2014 00:00:00 |
|      July, 01 2014 00:00:00 |
|     March, 10 2016 00:00:00 |
|     March, 11 2016 00:00:00 |
```